# textview background does not change for the selected_state

Tags: android

there are a few textviews in my layout. i want to change the color of selected textview. i think textview is not selectable, but is there anyway that i can set the background of for released state?

this is my text view:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/langDutch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/item_selected"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_settings_dutchon_hc_2x"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Dutch"
                android:textColor="#454C52" />
```

this is my item_selected.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/background_grey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_hc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_bf" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Are you sure the three different colors are in your strings.xml file?

Comment: @Mobstaa yes, colors are there.

Comment: Can you try using android:background instead of android:drawable?

Comment: @Mobstaa item deosn't support background

Answer (score -1):

First of all change this in the layout, in order to use the selector:

```
android:background="@drawable/item_background"
```

Then in it, write this (considering you want just the background, when it's unselected and the default):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_hc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_grey" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

Those are for the two possible states- focused and unfcused (pressed/unpressed).

Answer (score -1):

You can add an `onClickListner` to a `TextView` and change the background like this:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes i have thought of the same, but the problem with this is that, i would need to iterate and un-select the rest of the view.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a default a default state, that is used whenever none of the given states are true. See below - The last item is used when none of the other states are true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/background_grey" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_hc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_bf" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/background_released"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

In onclick for textview you have to call setSelected(true) for view.
Then it will render state_select color

```
onclick(View v){
 v.setSelected(true);
}
```